# Extending Chef IIS Pool LWRP

Tags: iis, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I would like to extend the Chef IIS Pool LWRP (https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/iis/blob/master/resources/pool.rb) and I was hoping someone could help me figure out the syntax.

This is where I'm at:
I created a new cookbook and then I referenced the IIS cookbook,
afterwards I created this file in the libraries folder of me:

```
# Located At: myCookbook/libraries/my_iis_pool.rb:
::Chef::Recipe.send(:include, Opscode::IIS)

class Chef
  class Resource::MyPool < Chef::Resource::IIS::Pool
    # Some Magic Happens
  end
end
```

and then the recipe looks like this:

```
# Located At: myCookbook/recipes/default.rb 
mypool 'new-pool' do
end
```

I can't seem to get the < Chef::Resource::IIS::Pool inherit statement correct. 
It produces this error:
*NameError: uninitialized constant Chef::Resource::IIS*

I've also tried

```
class Resource::MyPool < Chef::ResourceResolver.resolve(:iis_pool)
```

which produces this error:
*TypeError: superclass must be a Class (NilClass given)*

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Abrehm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't a good way to directly extend a DSL-based custom resource like that. The best approach is to just make a new custom resource that uses `iis_pool` internally, so kind of like a wrapper pattern. This only lets you do stuff before or after the existing resource code though, if that isn't enough you may have to dig in to some more exciting metaprogramming like the `edit_resource` APIs or declaring the classes in recipe files.